# Is the following limit of an integral positive?

Tags: probability, integration, limits

In one of my problems I need to show if the following holds

$$0<\lim_{{g\rightarrow f},\,{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}}\int_\mathbb{R}\log^2(g/f)(g/f)^\alpha f \, \mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$$

Here $g$ and $f$ are some continuous probability density functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is some suitable measure.

For $g=f$, the integral is obviously $0$. I conclude that for any other large $\alpha$, and $g$ very close to $f$, the integral should be positive because $\log^2$ is positive and $(g/f)^\alpha f$ is positive for all $\alpha.$ Is this enough to conlude that the limit is a positive number?

Comment: You want to take two limits. In which order do you want to take them? Or do you want the limit to be independent of order? Or do you want that if $\alpha_i\to\infty$ and $g_i\to f$ (in some sense), then the limit $\lim_{i\to\infty}\int\log^2(g_i/f)(g_i/f)^{\alpha_i}fd\mu\in(0,\infty)$? What do you exactly want? It can make a huge difference.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta just the last one that you've mentioned. Of course I will be happy to hear something more about the other cases.Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Then I doubt it's true. If $g_i\to f$ much slower than $\alpha\to\infty$ and $g_i>f>c>0$ on some interval, it seems that one should be able to cook up a counterexample where the limit is infinite. I'm not perfectly sure as I haven't done (and am unwilling to do) the detailed calculation, but I'm doubtful.